# My Ruby on Rails application pages only print JSON data, does not read any HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use foundation-rails to create a nice website, but for some reason application.html.erb is not being read, and only JSON data generated from a .csv file is being shown.

I've tried changing a lot of variables based on what I could find online, but it's difficult to know what's correct now since a lot of guides for foundation-rails is around 5 years old now. I just can't seem to render application.html.erb at all, no matter what the contents of the file are.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Large Speaker","price":199.99,"inventory_count":3,"description":"Very large. Loud? Prone to breaking.","created_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.080Z","updated_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.080Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Small Speaker","price":299.99,"inventory_count":34,"description":"Very small. Ineffective, but stylish.","created_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.083Z","updated_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.083Z"},{"id":3,"name":"Wrench","price":29.99,"inventory_count":1,"description":"Good for fixing speakers.","created_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.086Z","updated_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.086Z"},{"id":4,"name":"Golden Plate","price":1.99,"inventory_count":104,"description":"It’s just paint. Probably toxic. Great for weddings.","created_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.088Z","updated_at":"2019-01-20T05:31:53.088Z"}]
```

This is what is displayed on localhost:3000/products. What should be displayed is a standard HTML page with a text box and maybe a button. No errors appear in my console, or Chrome's console.

I'm also not entirely sure which code snippets or files I should share, considering I'm still new to Rails. Please let me know if there's anything you want to take a closer look at.

EDIT:

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

    <body>
        <!--Various elements-->
        <%= yield %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    render "application.html.erb", json: @products
  end

  # GET /products/1
  def show
    render json: @product
  end

  # POST /products
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      render json: @product
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :inventory_count, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you share your entire `application.html.erb` please?

Comment: You should probably also share the code for the controller and view in question.

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran I've added the files in question, please take a look!

Comment: @kaspernj I've also added products_controller.rb